# Creating a multi-header table from JSON

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm new to pandas. I'm trying to create the following table:

```
        |          C         |          Perl      |
        |   line   |   func  |    line   |   func |
version |  covered |  total  |  covered  |  total |
```

There is the following structure of JSON that I have created:

```
{
   "version1":{
      "perl":{
         "line_covered":207,
         "line_total":312,
         "func_covered":15,
         "func_total":18
      },
      "C":{
         "line_covered":321,
         "line_total":512,
         "func_covered":10,
         "func_total":10
      }
   }
}
```

I want to iterate over this JSON and create the table. My first problem is that I can't seem to understand how should I create the header of the table. From previous topics, I found that I should use `MultiIndex` but for some reason, any combination I tried, does not create the wanted header.  Is it possible to show me how to create this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My approach**

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
```

---

```
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    d['index'].append(k)
    for k1,v1 in v.items():
        for k2,v2 in v1.items():
            d['columns'].append((k1,k2))
            d['data'].append(v2)
d = dict(d)
d['data'] = np.array(d['data']).reshape(1, len(d['data']))
d['columns'] = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
```

---

**Build DataFrame**

```
pd.DataFrame(**d)
```

**Output**

```
                 perl                                               C                       
         line_covered line_total func_covered func_total func_covered           func_total   
version1          207        312           15         18           10  version1         10
```

use `defaultdict` but could just start three lists before starting the loop

**EDIT**

for expected output use

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    d['index'].append(k)
    for k1,v1 in v.items():
        for k2,v2 in v1.items():
            split = k2.split('_')
            d['columns'].append((k1, split[0]))
            d['data'].append(split[1])
d = dict(d)
d['data'] = np.array(d['data']).reshape(1,len(d['data']))
d['columns'] = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d['columns']).copy()
pd.DataFrame(**d)
```

---

**Output**

```
             perl                               C       
             line   line     func   func     func   func
version1  covered  total  covered  total  covered  total
```

*Details*

```
print(d)
#{'index': ['version1'], 'columns': MultiIndex([('perl', 'line_covered'),
#            ('perl',   'line_total'),
#            ('perl', 'func_covered'),
#            ('perl',   'func_total'),
#            (   'C', 'func_covered'),
#            (   'C',   'func_total')],
#           ), 'data': array([[207, 312,  15,  18,  10,  10]])}
```

you can see what[`**`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) do

Comment: numpy library, you need import numpy as np,

Comment: I see. For some reason I get `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 8 into shape (1,1)` on line `d['data'] = np.array(d['data']).reshape(1,len(data))`

Comment: upps sorry you need `.reshape(1,len(d['data'])` I use `data` and I forgot remove it. Solution update

Comment: Thanks! I tried to print `d` but I get `{'index': ['version1'], 'columns': MultiIndex(levels=[['C', 'perl'], ['func', 'line']],
           labels=[[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]]), 'data': array([['covered', 'total', 'covered', 'total', 'covered', 'total',
        'covered', 'total']], dtype='<U7')}`. Not sure why. If I print `**d`, it does not show the numbers.

Comment: Your are welcome :), We use `**` in order to pass arguments to `pd.DataFrame` object, you can see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters ,  you can check : `dict(**d) == d` is True

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But the result, does not show numbers at all. On the third line you get: `version covered  total  covered  total  covered  total  covered  total`

Comment: but if you want to show the values ​​you must use the first code

Comment: Oh sorry! I though it was the same code. what is `columns` in the first code?

Comment: check `df.columns` where df is your dataframe

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**

```
df = pd.json_normalize(my_dict, sep='_')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip(*df.columns.str.split('_')))
df = df.stack(level=0).droplevel(0)
```

---

We can use `pd.json_normalize`. Since it joins the column names at different depths with `.`s, one can split the column names and create a `pd.MultiIndex` from the resulting tuples:

```py
>>> df = pd.json_normalize(my_dict)
>>> tuple_cols = df.columns.str.split('.')
>>> df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuple(i) for i in tuple_cols)
```

We can also transpose with `zip` and use `from_arrays`:

```py
>>> df = pd.json_normalize(my_dict)
>>> df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip(*df.columns.str.split('.')))
```

Either way, `df` becomes the following:

```
      version1                                                                                   
          perl                                               C                                   
  line_covered line_total func_covered func_total line_covered line_total func_covered func_total
0          207        312           15         18          321        512           10         10
```

Because you seem to consider your keys concatenated with `_`, we may use that too:

```py
>>> df = pd.json_normalize(my_dict, sep='_')
>>> df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip(*df.columns.str.split('_')))
>>> df
```

```
  version1                                                
      perl                           C                    
      line          func          line          func      
   covered total covered total covered total covered total
0      207   312      15    18     321   512      10    10
```

But still, as far as I understand, the first level of your dictionary is actually the row name. So let's stack the first column level and drop the old index (I'm creating a second entry for clarity):

```py
>>> my_dict['version2'] = my_dict['version1']
>>> df = pd.json_normalize(my_dict, sep='_')
>>> df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip(*df.columns.str.split('_')))
>>> df
```

```
  version1                                     version2                                    
      perl                     C                   perl                     C              
      line    func          line          func     line    func          line          func
     total covered total covered total covered    total covered total covered total covered
0      312      15    18     321   512      10      312      15    18     321   512      10
```

```
>>> df = df.stack(level=0).droplevel(0)
```

And you're good to go:

```
               C                  perl            
            func    line          func        line
         covered covered total covered total total
version1      10     321   512      15    18   312
version2      10     321   512      15    18   312
```

**Tip:** If your JSON doesn't have all levels occupied, i.e. the actual values are in different depths, you may consider using `itertools.zip_longest`:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

df = pd.json_normalize(my_dict)
tuple_cols = df.columns.str.split('.')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip_longest(*tuple_cols))
```