# Reading a json as Multiindex DataFrame

Tags: json, pandas, numpy

I have a json which comprises like this.

```
[
    {
        "bi-document-identifier": "USA",
        "text": "I found somwthing Interesting",
        "relation_type": "ImportanceRelation",
        "annotation_type": "Opinionholder",
        "relation_start": {
            "annotatedtext": "We",
            "annotatedtext_represents": "OpinionHolder",
            "annotatedtext_startposition": 146,
            "annotatedtext_endposition": 148
        },
        "relation_end": {
            "annotatedtext": "information",
            "annotatedtext_represents": "StanceTarget",
            "annotatedtext_startposition": 239,
            "annotatedtext_endposition": 250
        }
    },
    {
        "bi-document-identifier": "USB",
        "text": "This is quite new to me",
        "relation_type": "ImportanceRelation",
        "annotation_type": "Opinionholder",
        "relation_start": {
            "annotatedtext": "Dr. A_PERSON",
            "annotatedtext_represents": "OpinionHolder",
            "annotatedtext_startposition": 0,
            "annotatedtext_endposition": 12
        },
        "relation_end": {
            "annotatedtext": "MOA of CV risk reduction",
            "annotatedtext_represents": "StanceTarget",
            "annotatedtext_startposition": 29,
            "annotatedtext_endposition": 53
        }
    }
]
```

how to read as a multi header dataframe. The orient and typ options in pandas.read_json() give me some errors like below

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from *read_json* with *records* orientation:

```
df = pd.read_json('Input.json', orient='records')
```

Then convert both *relation* columns to "MultiIndexed" version:

```
d = { tt: df[tt].apply(pd.Series) for tt in ['relation_start', 'relation_end'] }
wrk1 = pd.concat(d, axis=1, keys=d.keys())
```

The added MultiIndex level is the **top** level (*relation_start* and *relation_end*)
and index keys in source values become the second level.

The third step is to convert 4 initial columns, also to MultiIndex version, but this
time the added level is the **second** level, containing only empty strings:

```
wrk2 = df.iloc[:, 0:4]
wrk2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([wrk2.columns, ['']])
```

And the last thing to do is to contatenate both *wrk* DataFrames (on the index):

```
result = wrk2.join(wrk1)
```

Or if you want a shorter code, don't create *wrk1* (*d* is enough), and place
corresponding expression in the final instruction:

```
result = wrk.join(pd.concat(d, axis=1, keys=d.keys()))
```

**Note**: `json_normalize` proposed in the other solution is undeniably shorter,
but the result has **plain** (single level) column index.
As I understood, you want just a **MultiIndex** on columns.

Comment: kudos. I appreciate your effort. Great. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use pandas' `json_normalize`?

```
from pandas import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(data)
df.head(2)
```

Otherwise, this seems to cover your specific usecase:

[Creating a multi-header table from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729245/creating-a-multi-header-table-from-json)

Comment: Nice quick Solution. Thanks for sharing!